# Add and get object in list by type

Tags: c#, generics, interface

Suppose I have a bunch of objects A, B, C, ... that implement multiple interfaces I1, I2, I3, ...

My objective is to have functions like these

```
public void AddObjectThatImplements<T>(T o){
    //add o to some data structure that stores objects that implement T
}

public List<T> GetInterfaces<T>(){
    //return all T instances from the list of who implements T
}
```

In the initialization method of each of these objects, I can add their interfaces into a any kind of data structure that can help making these functions work.

For simplicity, all interfaces I1, I2, ... inherit from a base interface I0.

How can I build such functions? Any additional data structure is welcome.

Comment: How about storing `o`s in a `List<Object>` in `AddObjectThatImplements`, and then in `GetInterfaces` use [`is operator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#is-operator) to build a `List<T>` for all objects in the first list that are `is T` ? I am aware that it ignores `T` in `AddObjectThatImplements` but it seems to implement the behavior you need.

Comment: One of the points of this is trying to separate objects by the type... I was imagining some sort of `Dictionary<Type, List<I0>>` or something similar, where I could quickly get all correct objects... of course if nothing better works, the `List<object>` is the way to go.

Comment: I posted it as an answer then (in case nobody comes with a better solution).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is the way to go:

```
public static Dictionary<Type, List<I0>> data = new();

public static void AddObjectThatImplements<T>(T t) where T : I0
{
    if (!data.ContainsKey(typeof(T))) data[typeof(T)] = new();
    data[typeof(T)].Add(t);
}

public static List<T> GetInterfaces<T>() where T : I0
{
    if (!data.ContainsKey(typeof(T))) return new();
    return data[typeof(T)].OfType<T>().ToList();
}
```

I'm still trying to find out how to remove this OfType from the GetInterfaces though... Looks like it can't cast from `I0` to `T` directly (which is normal since `T` is a subclass of `I0`) so I need this currently.

Comment: No doubt this is a more sophisticated solution than mine. But what is the actual benefit it offers over my simple one (also added a note there about restricting the usage of `AddObject`) ? Maybe I could see that if you could explain more about your requirements.

Comment: The benefit is I can explicitly say the type that I'm adding in `AddObjectThatImplements<T>`, so that it makes easy to me to find any code which implements a certain interface simply by looking at the usages of the method. The second benefit is that I don't need to iterate over a list to find all elements of a given type, since I can find this in O(1) with a dictionary.

Comment: Fair enough, I understand your requierment better now (+1). Although applying big-O analysis is relevant only when the number of objects is relatively large. For a relatively small collection a simple approach also has advantages.

Answer (score 0):

You can store all your objects in a `List<I0>`.
Then in `GetInterfaces` use the [**is operator**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#is-operator), to build a new list of all objects in the first one that are `is T`.

From the documentation, the `is` operator is `true` in particular when:

> - The run-time type of an expression result is T.
> - The run-time type of an expression result derives from type T, implements interface T, or another implicit reference conversion
>   exists from it to T.

I am aware that it ignores `T` in `AddObjectThatImplements` but it seems to implement the behavior you need.

Therefore in the example below I renamed `AddObjectThatImplements` to simply `AddObject`:

```
public class Example
{
    private List<I0> all_objects = new List<I0>();

    public void AddObject(I0 o)
    {
        all_objects.Add(o);
    }

    public List<T> GetInterfaces<T>()
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        foreach(I0 o in all_objects)
        {
            if (o is T)
            {
                list.Add((T)o);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

---

Update:
As [commented below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78170700/add-and-get-object-in-list-by-type/78170780?noredirect=1#comment137812555_78170780), `GetInterfaces` can be implemented more elegantly using **LINQ** (requires `using System.Linq;`) - keeping the same behavior:

```
public List<T> GetInterfaces<T>()
{
    return all_objects.OfType<T>().ToList();
}
```

Comment: Note that `GetInterfaces` could be implemented very easily as `all_objects.OfType<T>().ToList()`

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks. That's indeed a lot more elegant. Will add that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is sample instance test for interfaces and classes.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RootObject instance = new();
        bool result = instance is BaseObject;
        Console.WriteLine(result);

        bool resultInterfaceCheck = instance is IBaseObject;
        Console.WriteLine(resultInterfaceCheck);


        var resultBothCheck = CheckInstanceType<BaseObject, IBaseObject>(instance);

        Console.WriteLine(resultBothCheck);

        // SAMPLE OF YOUR QUESTION

        List<RootObject> rootObjects = [];

        if (resultBothCheck)
        {
            rootObjects.Add(instance);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    public static bool CheckInstanceType<T, K>(object instance)
        where T : class
        where K : IBaseObject
    {

        Type instanceType = instance.GetType();

        return instanceType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(T)) || typeof(K).IsAssignableFrom(instanceType);
    }
}

public class RootObject : BaseObject, IBaseObject
{ }

public class BaseObject : IBaseObject
{ }

public interface IBaseObject { }
```

But you can also use it in static extension method like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool CheckInstanceType<T, K>(this object instance)
        where T : class
        where K : IBaseObject
    {

        Type instanceType = instance.GetType();

        return instanceType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(T)) || typeof(K).IsAssignableFrom(instanceType);
    }
}


public class UsedIn
{
    List<RootObject> rootObjects = [];
    RootObject instance = new();

    public void Add()
    {
        if (instance.CheckInstanceType<BaseObject, IBaseObject>())
        {
            rootObjects.Add(instance);
        }
    }

}
```

Either way if you want to use it for **multiple type of interfaces** you can just mark all that interfaces with BaseInterface

```
public interface IBaseObject : IMarkedInterface { }

public interface IShapedObject : IMarkedInterface { }

public interface IMarkedInterface { }

public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool CheckInstanceType<T, K>(this object instance)
        where T : class
        where K : IMarkedInterface
    {

        Type instanceType = instance.GetType();

        return instanceType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(T)) || typeof(K).IsAssignableFrom(instanceType);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your requirements it is super simple just to use the built-in `List<T>` and `OfType<T>()` code.

Just like this:

```
var instances = new List<I0>();

var instances_I2 = instances.OfType<I2>();
```

There doesn't seem to be a compelling reason to do more than this, unless you're not explaining your full problem.